# Как прописать правильно путь к элементу?

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Есть форма, а в ней кнопка. По нажатию на кнопку нужно взять значение атрибута формы action и записать в переменную его значение. Пример:

```
 <script>
 $(document).on ('click', '.submit-button', function() {

var path = $(this).parent //?????
var action = $(path).atr('action'); //тут все понятно

});
</script>
    <form action="target.php" class="edit-form" method="post" autocomplete="off">
            <fieldset>
                <div class="row">
                    <label for="addVideo_description">Описание</label>
                    <textarea id="addVideo_description" name="description" class="text-area" contenteditable="true"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="frame">
                        <input type="button" class="submit-button" value="Добавить"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

Главная задача сделать так, что бы это было универсально. Что бы при изменении формы, порядка и количества элементов внутри нее решение работало. Так же необходимо учесть, что на странице может быть несколько форм. Главное найти экшн той формы, в которой лежит кнопка с классом submit_button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var path = $(this).closest('.edit-form');
var action = path.attr('action');
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что надо!